# structure in C- to add a attribute at runtime?

Tags: c, programming-languages

how to add a member variable/attribute to a structure from main in C?

Comment: If you are asking this question to solve a problem, then may want to explain your problem. That way you get answers different to: "No!".

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218947/convert-a-string-in-c-code is related (but not a duplicate), and you might find some help there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. C is not a dynamic programming language.

You can, however, define an array in your struct; and allocate memory to that array. Perhaps this can solve your current problem?

Comment: You don't allocate memory to an array, you allocate memory to a pointer. An array is stored directly in the `struct` and is a different beast.

Comment: @Chris: I see what you're saying, but it isn't all that clear.  The answer, perhaps, should say: "You can, however, define a pointer in your structure, and you can dynamically allocate memory for an array and place the pointer to that allocated array in the structure (probably with a counter too)".

Comment: @Chris while from a technical standpoint that's true, I think the semantics were clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can't in any normal fashion.  Your structs need to be defined on compile.  If you have a bunch of like-items that need to be dynamically added considering setting up a resizeable array as a member.